# Move files from one folder to another Node js

Tags: node.js, file-io

I am reading one csv file and creating folder and trying to move those files into that folder..But i am getting error.

I am moving the file in .on('end', function(data)..

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, rename 'c:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\project\Nodejs\Attachments\00P9000001LiuvWEAR' -> 'c:\Users\XXXXXXX\Desktop\project\Nodejs\00190

 var csv = require('fast-csv');
  var fs = require('fs-extra');
  var attachmentIDs;
  var recordId;
  var dir;
  var dir1;
  var stream = fs.createReadStream('./Attachment.csv')
      .pipe(csv({
          headers: true
      }))
      .on('data', function(data) {
          recordId = data.Id;
          attachmentIDs = data.ParentId;
          dir = './' + attachmentIDs + '/';
          dir1 = './' + attachmentIDs + '/' + recordId + '/';
          if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
              fs.mkdirSync(dir);
          }
          if (!fs.existsSync(dir1)) {
              fs.mkdirSync(dir1);
          }
      })
      .on('end', function(data) {
          var oldPath = './Attachments/' + recordId;
          var newPath = dir1;
          fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function(err) {
              if (err) {
                  console.log(err);
              } else {
                  console.log("Files Moved");
              }
          });
      });
```

CSV content from the csv file i am reading

```
Id             IsDeleted    ParentId
00P9000001B22QqEAJ  0   0019000001rYSf9AAG
00P9000001FDf6uEAD  0   a0f9000000VM4TJAA1
00P9000001FDxFQEA1  0   a0f9000000VM4fqAAD
00P9000001FDxSuEAL  0   a0f9000000VM4g5AAD
00P9000001G7nAnEAJ  0   a0f9000000WQ21hAAD
00P9000001G7nAoEAJ  0   a0f9000000WQ21iAAD
00P9000001HGYppEAH  0   0019000001uJKSUAA4
00P9000001HGZ0xEAH  0   0019000001uJKSUAA4
00P9000001ISO9vEAH  0   0019000001xZCYlAAO
00P9000001ISPbmEAH  0   0019000001xZCYlAAO
00P9000001ISPecEAH  0   0019000001xZCYlAAO
00P9000001ITqDFEA1  0   0019000001xZCYlAAO
00P9000001JODmGEAX  0   0019000001xbZz1AAE
00P9000001KTviTEAT  0   0019000001yZmjcAAC
00P9000001LiuvREAR  0   0019000000ySYCvAAO
00P9000001LiuvWEAR  0   0019000000ySYCvAAO
```

Comment: `on('data')` receives chunks of data from the stream. You need to save it somewhere and then wait until `on('end')` and then write the file.

Comment: See: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end

Comment: Hi Brahma Dev....I have edited my code...i m using on('end') but still getting error

Comment: Sorry, I misread the code. I think you're trying to move one file per row of CSV. In which case, your older code was right. I'll post an answer for that.

Comment: sure brahma dev...thank u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed `recordId` and `attachmentIDs` from outermost scopes as they don't need to be shared across `data` events and were possibly polluting `dir` and `dir1` because of the asynchronous nature.

```
var csv = require('fast-csv');
var fs = require('fs-extra');
var mv = require('mv');
var stream = fs.createReadStream('./Attachment.csv')
    .pipe(csv({
        headers: true
    }))
    .on('data', function(data) {
        var dir = './' + data.ParentId + '/';
        var dir1 = './' + data.ParentId + '/' + data.Id + '/';
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(dir);
        }
        if (!fs.existsSync(dir1)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(dir1);
        }
        var oldPath = './Attachments/' + data.Id;
        var newPath = dir1 + data.Id;
        fs.move(oldPath, newPath, err => {
            if (err) return console.error(err);
            console.log('success!');
        });
    });
```

Comment: Getting an error - Error: EEXIST: file already exists, link 'c:\Users\XXXXX\Desktop\project\Nodejs\Attachments\00P9000001FDxFQEA1' -> 'c:\Users\XXXXXX\Desktop\project\Nodejs\a0f9000000V

Comment: Are you sure those files didn't exists before you ran the code. And also that there are no duplicate rows in the csv.

Comment: I meant duplicate rows(same `Id` and `ParentId` twice), not duplicate values. It'd nicer if you can include the part of the CSV where it is failing. Around `00P9000001FDxFQEA1`

Comment: Id wont be duplicate .. only parentId will be duplicate

Comment: while debugging.. i saw code is creating parentId folder and under each parentID it is creating another folder of Id..But it is not moving the files at that time...Do we need to add condition , if path exsists..